# how can i put the product details in search result?

Tags: magento2

can anyone help me with this problem?

i want to add product description in my search result.

sorry im new to magento.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using Any Module for Sort By @August Christopher Paras

Comment: @Learing_Coder yes

Comment: so you want solutions for sort or magento default search with description.